# rich:calendar unknown event

Tags: jquery, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `rich:calender` and I want to click (`textbox`) `rich:calendar` (so that it show me the calendar) using jqyery like

**HTML**

```
<rich:calendar id="newStartDate" datePattern="dd/M/yy" showFooter="false" showWeeksBar="false"
    buttonLabel="" jointPoint="topLeft" direction="topRight" inputClass="required"
    value="#{myBean.startDate}" cellWidth="18px" cellHeight="18px" >
```

Note: `<h:form>` I use with `prependId=false`.

**JQuery**

```
// Due to some event
$('#newStartDate').click();
```

But above jquery donot show popup(calendar). I want to know that which event is bind with `rich:calendar` that open popup(calendar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the id probably isn't `newStartDate` but something like `form:newStartDate`. The click listener isn't bound to the whole calendar but to the input box (form:newStartDateInputDate) so you'd use:

```
$('#form\\:newStartDateInputDate').click();
```

However RichFaces components have their own JS API so you can just do:

```
RichFaces.component('form:newStartDate').showPopup();
```

see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-calendar-JavaScript_API).

Comment: Well for `<h:form>` I use `prependId=false`.